# DoJo get/set overriding possible

Tags: dojo

I don't know much about Dojo but is the following possible:

I assume it has a getter/setter for access to its datastore, is it possible to override this code.

For example:

In the dojo store i have 'Name: @Joe'

is it possible to check the get to:

get()

```
if name.firstChar = '@' then just
return 'Joe'
```

and:

```
set(var)
if name.firstChar = '@' then set to @+var
```

Is this sort of thing possible? or will i needs a wrapper API?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the best doc from http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojo/data/api/Read

First, for getting the data from a store you have to use

```
getValue(item, "key")
```

I believe you can solve the problem the following way. It assumes you are using a ItemFileReadStore, you may use another one, just replace it.

```
dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore");
dojo.declare("MyStore", dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore, {
    getValue:function(item, key){
        var ret = this.inherited(arguments);
        return ret.charAt(0)=="@" ? ret.substr(1) : ret;
    }
})
```

And then just use "MyStore" instead of ItemFileReadStore (or whatever store you are using).
I just hacked out the code, didn't try it, but it should very well show the solution.
Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I believe so. I think what you'll want to do is read this here and determine how, if it will work:

The following statement leads me to believe the answer is yes:

> ...
>   By requiring access to go through
>   store functions, the store can hide
>   the internal structure of the item.
>   This allows the item to remain in a
>   format that is most efficient for
>   representing the datatype for a
>   particular situation. For example, the
>   items could be XML DOM elements and,
>   in that case, the store would access
>   the values using DOM APIs when
>   store.getValue() is called.
>
> As a second example, the item might be
>   a simple JavaScript structure and the
>   store can then access the values
>   through normal JavaScript accessor
>   notation. From the end-users
>   perspective, the access is exactly the
>   same: store.getValue(item,
>   "attribute"). This provides a
>   consistent look and feel to accessing
>   a variety of data types. This also
>   provides efficiency in accessing items
>   by reducing item load times by
>   avoiding conversion to a defined
>   internal format that all stores would
>   have to use.
>   ...
>    Going through store accessor function
>   provides the possibility of
>   lazy-loading in of values as well as
>   lazy reference resolution.

http://www.dojotoolkit.org/book/dojo-book-0-9/part-3-programmatic-dijit-and-dojo/what-dojo-data/dojo-data-design

I'd love to give you an example but I think it's going to take a lot more investigation.